# Prove that $\lVert L(x)\rVert \leq C\cdot \lVert x \rVert$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have to prove the next statement:

Let $\ L:\ \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ lineal. Then, there's a constant $C$ such that  $\lVert  L(x)\rVert \leq C\cdot \lVert x \rVert$, with $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

My professor said that

\begin{equation}
L(x)=L\big(\lVert x\rVert \cdot \frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}\big)=\lVert x\rVert L\big(\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}\big),
\end{equation}

but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggestion shows that it's sufficient to prove that, for any $x$ with $||x|| = 1$, $||L(x)|| \leq C$ for some $C$ (independent of $x$).

Suppose that this *isn't* the case; for any $C$, you can find $x$ with $||x||= 1$ such that $||L(x)|| > C$. This means $L$ is unbounded on the unit sphere. The unit sphere is compact. What contradictions arise?

Comment: By Weierstrass, L is bounded, so it leads to a contradiction, right? Thank you!

Comment: Yep! You're welcome.

Comment: Wait, I dont see how this is true. Are you supposing T is continuous?

Comment: Fair objection; OP, if you can't assume $L$ is continuous to begin, then you can show it is bounded on the unit sphere by taking an orthonormal basis ($L$ is trivially bounded on a finite set of vectors), then writing any $x$ in the unit sphere as a linear combination of these basis vectors and going from there.